# How to do a query in Android using Parse?

Tags: android, parse-platform

My Class in parse is called "MyClass" and this one has several objects like

```
| ObjectId | Names | owners | users | (owners is a pointer of another class)
```

I want to do a query that gives me all of the names in my object "Names" that belong to the owner but, when I do this query i get this:

```
com.parse.ParseObject@41828fe0
com.parse.ParseObject@41829fdd
com.parse.ParseObject@4182aa28
```

my code is this

```
final ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("MyClass");
query.whereEqualTo("owners", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {
    public void done( List<ParseObject> MyList, ParseException e) {

        if (e == null) {

            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ParseObject>(MyActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, MyList);
            listDev.setAdapter(adapter);

        }else{
            //error
        }
```

please help me how to do that query that gives me all of name that belong to the owner.

**EDIT**
I found a solution and is something like this.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("MyClass");
        ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        query.whereEqualTo("owners", user);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (ParseObject parseObject : objects){
                        String task;
                        task= parseObject.get("owners").toString();
                        adapter.add(task);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                } else {
                    // Something went wrong.
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Error: " + e.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your real problem here is your ArrayAdapter. You would need a custom adapter if you want to use Parse objects as your data type. The built in adapter doesn't know how to use Parse objects and is outputting the object as a string for you. Instead you should do something like

`arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, MyNamesList);`

Where `MyNamesList` is of type `String`.

It's hard to help on your query without more information but you are getting Parse objects back, you just need to get the name out of them with something like

`MyList.get(i).getString("name");`

Answer (score 0):

somewhere outside the query method

```
    private ArrayList<YourObjectType> list;

public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (objects == null || objects.size() == 0) {
                return; //no objects
            }
                list = new ArrayList<YourObjectType>();
            for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {


                    YourObjectType myObject = new YourObjectType();
                    ParseObject object = objects.get(i);

                    myObject.objectId = object.getObjectId();
                    myObject.names = object.get("Names");
                    myObject.owners = object.get("owners");
                    myObject.users = object.get("users");
                    list.add(myObject);


            }



      adapter = new ArrayAdapter<YourObjectType>(MyActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, MyList);
      listDev.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

now set the list to your adapter

your adapter should be able to handle objects of your type, so i think you need to create a custom adapter, the one provided by the android sdk, won't do here

Answer (score 0):

The solution is pretty easy, since you are getting com.parse.whatever, all u need to do is ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
Then query.whereequalto("owner", user.getUsername());

The problem was, u where querying for currentUser instead of usernames.